# How to implement AWS API Gateway WebSocket heartbeat?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to figure out how to implement heartbeat on ApiGateway WebSocket.

I understand that WebSocket close after 10 minutes, so I need to send a ping to a server to keep a connection alive.

I set up client code like this.

```
  const socket = new WebSocket('wss://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/Prod');
  socket.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
            console.log('WebSocket error: ', event);
          });
  socket.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
            console.log('open',event);
            setInterval(ping,60000)
          });
  socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
            console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
          });

  function ping() {
    const res = socket.send(JSON.stringify({"action":"pong"}));
    console.log("ping");
  }
```

And this is the lambda function set for pong and $default path.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = event => {
  console.log("pong");
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: "pong"
  };
};
```

When `socket.send(JSON.stringify({"action":"pong"}));` being executed, I receive errors say `[Log] Message from server  – "{\"message\": \"Internal server error\", \"connectionId\":\"VUeh8f60tjMCF1A=\", \"requestId\":\"VUelwHaYtjMFcJw=\"}"`

I enabled error logs on WebSocket API, I found logs like

```
{
    "requestId": "VUek0FQXtjMFYbg=",
    "ip": "XX.XX.XX.XXX",
    "caller": "-",
    "user": "-",
    "requestTime": "15/Jul/2022:17:59:07 +0000",
    "eventType": "MESSAGE",
    "routeKey": "$default",
    "status": "502",
    "connectionId": "VUeh8f60tjMCF1A="
}
```

I expect the routeKey to be like `"routeKey": "pong"`, but $default path is executed and returns 502 errors. In order to return the response to the client, I need to use postToConnection function of ApiGatewayManagementApi, but my goal is to keep the connection alive with the same connectionId. I can't understand why I am getting this error. Both $default and $connection path don't have an integration response, but $connection path returns 200 after a connection being made.

I expect to receive something like `[Log] Message from server - Event {isTrusted : true, type: "message", target: Websocket, ...}` on client, but I keep receiving errors. I want to get rid of this.

My question is, How to keep a connection alive after 10 minutes correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `exports.handler = event =>` to `exports.handler = async event =>` then everything worked as expected.

Comment: I don't think you need to implement a lambda for the pong it is part of the Websocket RFC to support pong and If you don't implement it yourself I think it is not charged as a message.